# quick filter of IP that's causing sendmail DOS under FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ip, sendmail, ipfw

I've got what appears to be a malicious/spam host that is overloading my Sendmail server causing it to refuse connections to other hosts.  I'm overloaded by connections from one particular IP address. This IP is blocked in /etc/access from us accepting mail but it's causing a DOS via the mail server which is limiting the number of simultaneous connections.

How can I block a particular IP address so it doesn't even get to sendmail?  I can't use inetd because sendmail is operating as a daemon.  Can I use something like ifpw?  I've never used it before.  This is FreeBSD 7.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't appear to have firewall capabilities, you could try using `tcpwrappers` to block the offending IP address. Under FreeBSD, `tcpwrappers` is configured in the file `/etc/hosts.allow`. Near the top of that file, add a line like this:

```
sendmail : ip.add.re.ss : deny
```

Even though, as you state, `sendmail` is not started by `inetd`, this will work, provided you are using a default build of `sendmail` - under FreeBSD, it is linked against `libwrap`, which provides this functionality. (If the output of `ldd /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail` doesn't include a reference to `lwrap`, then all bets are off, I'm afraid...)

Note that this is not a substitute for a real firewall - but in this case, it might just save you until this idiot moves on to his next victim. You should consider upgrading to a more recent release of FreeBSD, and take the opportunity to configure a firewall at the same time.

Comment: I don't think my sendmail build is default - I may have compiled it myself.. is there a way to test this?  I've never been able to block mail before in /etc/hosts.allow though I never tried

Comment: Run `ldd /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail` If you see a line that refers to `libwrap`, you should be able to use tcpwrappers, no matter who compiled it. Make sure the `hosts.allow` rule is early enough in the file that it isn't masked by the default `ALL : ALL : allow`, which allows all services to all callers. If you don't see `libwrap`, you can rebuild sendmail with default options to get the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [the firewall builtin to FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html).  You can add a rule to drop packets from specific hosts so that the sendmail daemon never sees them.

Comment: can anyone give me a quick example on how to temporarily create a rule to filter a particular IP?   And then revoke it?

Comment: when I do:  ipfw list

I get: 

ipfw: getsockopt(IP_FW_GET): Protocol not available